# What are the crash guarantees of rename by an extra hardlink?

Tags: data-recovery, btrfs, crash

## Origin

From https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/FAQ#What_are_the_crash_guarantees_of_overwrite-by-rename.3F

> Overwriting an existing file using a rename is atomic. That means that either the old content of the file is there or the new content. A sequence like this:
>
> ```bsh
> echo "oldcontent" > file
>
> # make sure oldcontent is on disk
> sync
>
> echo "newcontent" > file.tmp
> mv -f file.tmp file
>
> # *crash*
> ```
>
> Will give either
>
> file contains "newcontent"; file.tmp does not exist 
> file contains "oldcontent"; file.tmp may contain "newcontent", be zero-length or not exists at all.

This approach guarantees to keep `file` consistent (it will have either "newcontent" or "oldcontent") but new data might or might not be recovered after a crash. (`mv file.tmp file` gives even [more interesting results](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/FAQ#What_are_the_crash_guarantees_of_rename.3F))

## Question

I wanted to achieve an approach to resume the operations in case of a crash, where I won't loose either "oldcontent" or "newcontent". How can I do that?

Would it guarantee to have:

- either `file` has "oldcontent" and `file.tmp` has "newcontent"
- or `file` has "newcontent" and `file.tmp` does not exist:

```bsh
echo "oldcontent" > file

echo "newcontent" > file.tmp

# make sure files are on disk
sync

# a crash may happen at any time starting from this point.

ln file.tmp file.tmp2
mv -f file.tmp2 file
rm file.tmp
```

Comment: You moved the `sync`; was that intentional?

Comment: Yes, it was intentional. I thought we could only expect the "newcontent" upon reboot if it's guaranteed to be written on the ... Wait, if we move the `sync` line after `echo "newcontent"` line in the original example, would it behave exactly as in my question?

Comment: Yes, moving the `sync` changes the guarantees: it ensures the content is on disk. The only uncertainty then is which file name points where.

Comment: I edit my question, so your latest comment becomes the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By moving the `sync` after `echo "newcontent" > file.tmp`, you’re ensuring that the contents of both files are on disk. This removes the “`files.tmp` may be zero-length” variant.

The remaining uncertainty, if a crash occurs after the `sync`, only concerns the directory entries, *i.e.* which file points where. After moving the `sync`, the remaining possibilities are those which you list:

- `file` exists and contains “oldcontent”, and `file.tmp` exists and contains “newcontent”;
- `file` exists and contains “newcontent”, and `file.tmp` doesn’t exist.

There’s no need to add additional failsafes by linking `file.tmp` elsewhere.

Moving the `sync` does have other consequences: in particular, it leaves more time for data loss to occur *before* the `sync`.